# How to refresh firebase token on Flutter?

Tags: firebase, token, flutter, messaging

I have a Flutter app that uses Firebase messaging to delivery notifications. 
This is the base code, it does nothing special, besides saving the token on my DB.

```
 FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {

  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {

  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {

  },
);


_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  saveToken(token);
});
```

Do I have to implement some kind of background service to keep saving the new token on my DB everytime it gets refreshed? I remember using `onTokenRefresh()` on Android(JAVA) to do this, but I found nothing about it in Flutter (DART).

I read somewhere that the token gets refreshed every 3600 seconds. I wonder if this is true.

Answer (score 22):

No, FCM token doesn't refresh every 3600 seconds. It only refreshes when :

1. When user **Uninstall/Reinstall** the app or **Clears App Data**
2. You manually delete FCM Instance using `FirebaseMessaging().deleteInstanceID()`

You can listen to token refresh stream using:

```
FirebaseMessaging().onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
   // Save newToken
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i'm writing this onTokenRefresh inside initstate and its calling everytime not only on getting new token its called and return old token too. i need this onTokenRefresh only calls on new token generated only.

Comment: Yes, as a workaround, you have to store the old token in sharedPreferences. Everytime you get a onTokenRefresh call, you can compare it with the one on SharedPreferences and store it only if they are different. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks brother, i'm also thinking like that.

Comment: @MSARKrish Glad I could help.

Comment: possible that this is the correct syntax?

`FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
  // Save newToken
});`

Comment: Just want to add that the method deleteInstanceID() is currently deprecated. Now you should call deleteToken() method instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onTokenRefresh.html) to get a stream which receives an event each time a new token is received.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of subscribing to the  [`firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onTokenRefresh.html) stream and updating the token if the token has changed:

```
FirebaseMessaging().onTokenRefresh.listen((token) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String firebaseTokenPrefKey = 'firebaseToken';
  final String currentToken = prefs.getString(firebaseTokenPrefKey);
  if (currentToken != token) {
    print('token refresh: ' + token);
    // add code here to do something with the updated token
    await prefs.setString(firebaseTokenPrefKey, token);
  }
});
```

Comment: `onTokenRefresh` only gets called when the token changes. You don't need any logic there.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try with this.. as per new updation

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
        // Save newToken
      });
```

Answer (score -4):

After the user logs in my app logs her in again automatically every 3500 seconds.

I used a Timer like this:

```
  void _timerPressed() {
    const timeout = const Duration(seconds: 3500);
    new Timer.periodic(timeout, (Timer t) => _handleSignIn());
  }
```

I set the timer in the 'login' button press method after the login has occurred:

```
  void _loginPressed() {
    print('The user wants to login with $_email and $_password');
    _handleSignIn()
        .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
        .catchError((e) => print(e));
    _timerPressed();
  }
```

(Don't be fooled by the name of the method, '_timerPressed'.  I used a button press for testing the technique and haven't gotten around to renaming the method after I tied it in to the login button.)

Comment: You don't even talk about FCM token in this post. FCM token is used for push notifications and is a totally different matter from authenticating user with firebase.